# modified .LESS file by adding extra rule for some HTML attribute but the changes are not reflecting in respective CSS file

Tags: html, css, less

i have added below code to my .LESS file where i am adding extra attribute for certain page level id(noprefereenceupdatelistids)

```
 #noprefereenceupdatelistids {
    .m-action-button .tertiary-btn {
        aria-disabled:false;
    }

    .submitAction .m-action-button .primary-btn .m-action-button .primary-btn {
        aria-disabled:false;
    }
}
```

Then I ran grunt command but the changes are not getting added in respective CSS file

HTML Button element for which i am trying to add extra attribute via .LESS file

```
<input id="PSD2InterstitialForm:btnCancelStmtFreqPref" name="PSD2InterstitialForm:btnCancelStmtFreqPref" value="Cancel" alt="Cancel" style="float:left;margin:10px" title="Cancel" src="/personal/assets/missingresource.png" class="m-action-button tertiary-btn" type="submit">
```

Generated CSS content as follows

```
.content input.m-action-button.tertiary-btn, .content a.m-action-button.tertiary-btn, .content .balanceTransfer div.actions input.m-action-button.tertiary-btn {
    padding: 0.95em;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: #006A4D;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: lloyds_bank_jack-mediumWEB,arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML and also the generated CSS section?

Comment: Added the relevant info.Basically for one HTML button element i am trying to add extra attribute via .LESS file